# Finding integrand that represents fraction of two integrals

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

I have a problem: I'm working on a big-ish proof and it all relies on whether I can express the fraction of integrals as one integral. Any tips on how I can even attempt to find $\mathcal{G}(\rho,\pi)?$

$$\frac{\int_{x\in A}\frac{2\rho(x)h(x)}{\pi(x)}\,dx}{\sqrt{\int_{x\in A}\frac{\rho^2(x)}{\pi(x)}\,dx}}=\int_{x\in A}\mathcal{G}(\rho,\pi)h(x)\,dx.$$

Some background info:
$\rho$ and $\pi$ are probability densities, h is an arbitrary functional (coming from taking directional derivative, along arbitrary direction)  and I need $\mathcal{G}$ to solve for $\rho$ in

$0=L(\theta)+\dfrac{k}{2}\,\mathcal{G}(\rho,\pi)-\bar{\lambda} $

It would be enough if I can find $\mathcal{G}$ for this specific problem, but more formally I'm looking for a solution to
$$\frac{\int\frac{df}{d\rho}\,dx}{\sqrt{\int f(\rho)\,dx}}=\int \mathcal{G}\,dx.$$

Also, worst case if closed form solution does not exists, it would be enough to find a way to compute the numerical value of $\rho(\theta_i)$, if I was given $\theta_i.$

Comment: Do you know what $h$ is? Also, is $\mathcal{G}$ a functional? It's not entirely clear how or why $\mathcal{G}$ depends on $\rho$ and $\pi.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister h is an arbitrary functional, i have now clarified it in the question

Comment: If $h=h(x),$ then it is a function, not a functional. $\mathcal{G}$ is a functional if it depends on the functions $\rho$ and $\pi.$ Which of $\rho, \pi,$ and $h$ can we consider to be known? Also, what's $\theta?$ You need to define every single unknown symbol in your question.